# Double Clicking Queries In a List Box to display The Exact Query

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a Listbox with a List of my queries, I need to be able to double-click one item on the List, and it displays its Query. How can I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
Private Sub QueryList_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    DoCmd.OpenQuery Me!QueryList.Value
    
End Sub
```